# Site preview cannot find files that exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me and a coworker are building an application in asp.net (C#).   Recently, I reorganized the file structure... I moved a file (login.aspx) from the root, to a sub-folder.  Everything works fine on my machine (in my development environment).

So I upload the changes to our source control solution (StarTeam), and my co-worker downloads the entire project (a complete fresh copy) to her box.   She opens the solution, and attempts to run it, and she get's an error that says the login.aspx page cannot be found in the location it is supposed to be at (inside that subfolder I talked about).  But when I look in the solution explorer, IT'S THERE!.

Moreover, while attempting to run the site, if I alter the path to look for the login page at it's original location (the root), it actually comes up.  BUT, if you look  in the solution explorer, no such file exists.

I've tried cleaning the solution, and rebuilding multiple times, but I keep getting the same results.  I'm especially flummoxed by the fact it can pull up a file that plainly doesn't exist in the solution.  It's like it's holding on to a cached version somehow regardless of my attempts to clean the solution.

Comment: Not sure but one of the probable cause can be Not committing Project solution file.

Comment: No url rewriters? How do you run the solution? IIS Express, Cassini?

Comment: what's your .aspx look like also are the paths hard coded on your machine or are you utilizing `~` or `../` convention when mapping to files or URLs hard to see what you have done or what you are trying without seeing any code where you are experiencing the issue and or problem. also did you add the files to the project in the solution..? one other important question did you do this as a `WebSite` or a `Web Application` there is a difference

Comment: "-1"?  Really?  I've reviewed my question multiple times, and I fail to see how it warrants a -1.  Frankly, some constructive critisism would be more helpful, than just an anonymous (possibly fly-by) -1.

One of the key pieces of info I included in my post, was that the solution runs fine in my development environment.  It was only on another developers box that we got the problem.

Comment: @mts1701 constructive criticism would be nice, but honestly just ignore the -1... it happens. I upvoted to negate it anyway... :-) Glad your figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another developer suggested that I clear out the temporary files built by .Net when the solution is built.  He pointed me to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root", and told me to delete the contents therein.

After I did that, the entire problem disappeared.  So it's my interpretation that when I use the "Clean Solution" feature under Build, that "everything" isn't actually cleaned.

I may be interpreting the evidence wrong, and if so, I welcome clarification.  However, I can attest that this solved my problem.